# How to intercept touch events from ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener

Tags: android, tabs, scroll, touch, android-viewpager

I'm trying to disallow my ViewPager from scrolling between tabs. I have the following situation:

```
        public class MyClass extends ViewPager implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, OnTouchListener {

             public MyClass() {
               setOnTouchListener(this);
             }

@Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        Log.d("Testing", TAG + " onPageScrollStateChanged");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        Log.d("Testing", TAG + " onPageScrolled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        Log.d("Testing", TAG + " onPageSelected");
    }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d("Testing", "intercept");
                return false;
        }

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.d("Testing", "touch2");
                    return false;
            }

        }
```

I have the logs from onPageScrolled and onPageScrollStateChanged normally, but I do not have logs from onInterceptTouchEvent and onTouch. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is how I handle this (my entire class) :

```
public class SelectiveViewPager extends ViewPager {
private boolean paging = true;

public SelectiveViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SelectiveViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet){
    super(context, attributeSet);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    if (paging) {
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(e);
    }

    return false;
}

public void setPaging(boolean p){ paging = p; }

}
```

The boolean `paging` gives you the option to turn this on and off, if you need it.  If you don't need, just `return false`. If you aren't doing anything special in `onTouch`, you don't need to override it.

Comment: Yes, this may work.. but the difference is that my class implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener. I think this is the problem because onPageScrollStateChanged, onPageScrolled and onPageSelected might use touchEvent, so all touchEvent caught by my application go to these methods. What's your opinion about that?

Answer (score 1):

`return true;` in your `onInterceptTouchEvent();`

Comment: This is not the problem because I can't even catch the logs from this method.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor doesn't get called btw. Are you creating the view pager by code or inflating it by xml? You need to define the proper constructors.

Comment: I'm creating my view pager inflating by xml. This is an resumed version of myClass. But the methods from OnPageChangeListener are running normally.

Comment: That class doesn't even compile. My point is that constructor must be defined in a proper way according to the way you instantiate your custom view. Anyway it could depend on the views hierarchy, for instance, is there any view/viewgroup that could intercept the touch event earlier?