# I want to dont change ViewPager pages when touching a specified view

Tags: android, android-viewpager, touch

I have a `ViewPager` with two pages. in page 1 is a chart with a movable pointer.
I want to when user changing the pointer location with touch, `ViewPager` pages dont change and stay on page 1.

[image]

Comment: plz take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764603/how-to-intercept-touch-events-from-viewpager-onpagechangelistener

Answer (score 0):

best and simple way you first migrate viewpager to viewpager 2 and then just one line code you can disable swiping touch page

`viewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(false);`
and enable
`viewPager2.setUserInputEnabled(enable);`

Please check : [Migrate from ViewPager to ViewPager2](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration)