# How to override a View's touch methods to make them listen continously

Tags: android, webview

I have a WebView, I want swiping on it should click everything underneath it.
I mean I am clicking (down) on 100,100 coordinates, and swiping all the way through coordinates 200,200 and clicking up.

I want every pixel 101,101; 102,102...199,199 to be clicked when I do it.

For this purpose I wrote my own class extending WebView, but still, I can't see any difference at all.

```
public class MyWebView extends WebView{

    public MyWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I made return parameters true, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If webview is a viewgroup (which i believe it is, but i could be wrong) you can use the ViewGroups onInterceptTouchEvent class for this. Though i do not know how you would implement that in this particular case, it should get you in the right direction.

[How to intercept touch events from ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764603/how-to-intercept-touch-events-from-viewpager-onpagechangelistener)